# how to create loop in loop...? PHP - MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I have table of data that store number into the rows. Now I wanna to create table with them. I want to crate `X` rows and `Y` columns. I know I should use while or `foreach` loop but I don't know how... :(

```
$result = $db->query(
        "SELECT `x`,`y`,`noe` FROM `table` "
      . "WHERE (`x` >= 0 and `x` < 4) and (`y` >= 0 and `y` < 4) "
      . "ORDER BY `x`,`y` ASC") or die($db->error);

if($result) {
    echo "<pre>",$result->num_rows,"</pre>";
    echo "<pre>",  print_r($row = $result->fetch_object()),"</pre>";
?>
<table>

<?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_all()){
        //echo "X: ", $row->x, " ,Y: ", $row->y," ,Type of item: ", $row->noe,"<br>";
        echo '<tr><td>',$row->x,'-',$row->y,'</td></tr>';
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: What does `X` rows and `Y` columns mean in this context?

Comment: @asprin I want to create something like this: http://uploadco.ir/uploads/ohxpfv53d09fx445odoj.png

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question. If you had a two-dimensional array, you're right you would loop over `x` first and then over each `y` for a given value of `x`. However your data, although it describes a two-dimensional structure, comes in a flat result. I'd loop over the rows, keep track of the last `x` and create new `<tr>..</tr>` every time you notice the `x` in your result is different from the one in the last iteration (ie the row has changed).

Something like

```
$lastx = -1; // or some value you know you'll never use
while ($row = $result->fetch_all()) {
  $x = $row['x'];
  if ($x != $lastx) {
     echo '<tr>';
  }
  echo '<td>...</td>'
  if ($x != $lastx) {
    echo '</tr>';
    $lastx = $x;
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to create something like this: http://uploadco.ir/uploads/ohxpfv53d09fx445odoj.png